# Is it OK to describe "sensors" as "sensing devices" in the same sentence?

Tags: word-choice

Would it be OK in a technical manual to describe "sensors" as "sensing devices" in the same sentence? If not, how could the act of sensing be described. I've thought of verbs like "to pick up", "to perceive", or "to detect" but they didn't sound good to me.

I'm trying to build up a sentence which starts like this:

"Alarms occur when various sensors sense conditions which/like etc..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the following definitions may help chose the correct terminology:

[Sensor](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sensor):

> - **A device for sensing and measuring** light, pressure, or temperature, and sending information back to a computer.
> - **A device that responds to a physical stimulus** and converts the stimulus into a signal conveyed to another device. For example, **a sensor in a printer detects** that the paper tray is empty and sends a signal to the digital display that the tray is out of paper.
> - **A device, such as a photoelectric cell, that receives and responds** to a signal or stimulus.
> - **a mechanical device sensitive to** light, temperature, radiation level, or the like, that transmits a signal to a measuring or control instrument.

- Alarms occur when various sensors detect .....

(TFD)

Comment: I hadn't expressed myself good enough and just edited my question. I'm trying to find out if it's OK to use them both in the same sentence.

Comment: I guess you can! http://www.rockwellautomation.com/rockwellautomation/products-technologies/sensing-devices/overview.page